# Pass button id using python main file: kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to pass an id to a button using python main file. This code used to work on previous versions of kivy. I just installed kivy 2.0 for this but it is returning the following error:

super(Widget, self).**init**(**kwargs)

File "kivy_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.**init**

TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

It works when I remove the id from the button

````
            btn = Button(text='Delete (X)', id="school", bold=True, color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                         background_color=(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1), size_hint=(None, None), font_size=15, size= 
                         (100, 25),
                         pos_hint=({'center_x': .5}), on_release=lambda btn: Education().delete(btn.id))```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584198/pass-dynamically-created-button-information-to-a-function-when-they-are-pressed

Answer (score 0):

The `id=` is not a legal argument to the `Button` constructor, so it gets passed along to `super` classes until it reaches the base class (`object`), which does not accept any arguments other than `self`. So it throws an exception.

If you are thinking of the `id` from the `kivy` language, note that the `id:` is special in the `kivy` language and is used to create a dictionary of widgets in the root widget of a rule. And the specified `id` is used in that dictionary, but does not become a property of the widget where it appears.

Comment: I downgraded to python 3.7.1 and kivy 1.11.1, and it now works as it used to do before the update. Thanks for the reply @JohnAnderson